# How to dynamically insert code before and after execution of each button tap event?

Tags: ios, objective-c, aop

I want to capture time taken to execute each button tap method, for that I need to insert code before and after execution of all button taps. Is there any way to do so in objective-C.I can capture all the touch events and figure it out if its a button but that wont solve the problem since I want to insert code before and after execution of those methods.
I tried Aspect Oriented Programming but for that we need to specify selector name.

How can we do this for all the button taps in a project?

Comment: If you just want to know the time, better to do profiling via Instruments

Comment: I want to capture that time from my app, not just for testing purpose.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do after you get the time? `touchBegin` and `touchEnd` should be the two end points you could access

Comment: When a user taps a button some action will be performed, I want to capture time taken to execute that action.

Comment: For all the buttons, for that I need to know is there any way by which we can dynamically insert code for this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I undestood what you want, but did you read about Tracking Touches? You can capture when you tap, when you untap and if you keep tapping.

Check it out: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/beginTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:

Just extends UIButton class, and override the methods what you want. In your case, I think you want to override the method 
- beginTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:

Insert any code before and after to call the method super, and you can capture the events before and after tap.

**Objective C**

```
- (BOOL)beginTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch
                 withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    //code before tapping
    [super beginTrackingWithTouch:touch
                 withEvent:event];
    //code after tapping
}
```

**Swift**

```
func beginTrackingWithTouch(touch: UITouch,
    withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool{
    //code before tapping
    super.beginTrackingWithTouch(touch, event);
    //code after tapping
}
```

If you want to capture the tappings for all UIButtons, create a category instead extends the class UIButton.

Sorry my bad english. Hope I helped you.

Comment: thanks for answer, This is not what i am searching for. My question is when we tap any button some action will be performed, I want to capture time taken in executing that action. for eg. suppose on a button tap we are fetching data from backend and then populating that into a list view, so I am interested to capture time taken to perform this whole action. For that I need to dynamically insert code before and after the execution of each button tap action i.e (IBAction).